# Flipping a shape with RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have created a Hexagon with RaphelJS, but I could not find a nice, easy tutorial on how I can flip the Hexagon.

Here is the current hexagon creation code:

```
function polygon(x, y, size, sides, rotate) {
var self = this;

self.centrePoint = [x,y];
self.size = size;
self.sides = sides;
self.rotated = rotate;
self.sizeMultiplier = 50;

self.points = [];

for (i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
    self.points.push([(x + (self.size * self.sizeMultiplier) * (rotate ? Math.sin(2 * 3.14159265 * i / sides) : Math.cos(2 * 3.14159265 * i / sides))), (y + (self.size * self.sizeMultiplier) * (rotate ? Math.cos(2 * 3.14159265 * i / sides) : Math.sin(2 * 3.14159265 * i / sides)))]);
}

self.svgString = 'M' + self.points.join(' ') + ' L Z';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 450, 450);

var path1 = new polygon(100, 100, 2, 6, false);
var path2 = new polygon(205, 187, 1, 6, false);
var path3 = new polygon(100, 277, 2, 6, false);

var hex1 = paper.path(path1.svgString);
var hex2 = paper.path(path2.svgString);
var hex3 = paper.path(path3.svgString);

hex1.node.id = "hex1";
hex1.attr("fill", "#ccc");
hex1.attr("stroke", "#aceace");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you wish to flip the hexagon? If you only wish to flip horizontally or vertically, you can use the [scale](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.scale) function. The documentation lists it like this:

```
Element.scale(sx, sy, [cx], [cy])
```

and you can insert a negative `sx` (flip horizontally) or `sy` (flip vertically). Since you want your hexagon to stay the same size, use the value `-1` for either:

```
hex1.scale(1,-1, 0, 0);
```

**Update**: Apparently the `scale` function has been deprecated, so you should use the `transform` function instead, and remember to adjust for translation after the scale (or scale around the center of the hexagon). So the code would look like this (with a 500ms ease out effect) :

```
hex1.animate({transform: "S-1,1"},500,'easeOut');
```

Or

```
hex1.transform("S-1,1")
```

without the animation effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Herman. I'm getting the JS Error [ self.centrePoint ] is undefined, which makes sense, cause that only exists within the scope of the function [ polygon ]. !

Comment: Oh, yes, that's a mistake on my part - but you can fix it yourself by just getting or calculating the actual center point of the hexagon. The answer to your question still remains the `-1` scale part.

Comment: Thanks Herman. What is the best way (easiest way) to compute the centre point of the Hexagon ?

Comment: With a pen and paper? :) Then put the formula in your code. Alternatively, you can flip it around the 0,0 axis, and then move it back by it's width/height. But if you have the width/height of your aligned hexagon in the first place, the centerpoint is of course just half that. Again, point of the matter is: flipping is done with the scale function - it will just leave your hexagon in another position if you don't flip it around the center, so then you have to move it back. If you have lots of trouble with that, maybe open another question.

Comment: Hehe, ok so after finding the x and y of the centre point of the hexagon, the scale code you provided did not work for me ! perhaps because it has been deprecated, so I use the [ transform ] function. Here is the code:

    hex1.animate({transform: "S-1,1"},500,'easeOut');

Comment: Ah yes, I see it's been deprecated now. Haven't used the library in a while. I'll update the answer :)